# Array from a textfile, and then display new values obtained from subtracting starting values by mean in android studio

Tags: java, android, arrays

I have already managed to display the values from a textfile and put them into an array (i think), but now i want to not only obtain new values equal to the original values minus the lehmer mean, but also output them to a file that displays one value per line and with a limit of four decimal places, but i have no idea where to even start with that.
This is the code I have right now:

```
public void processPress(View view)
        throws IOException
{
    EditText fileInputField = findViewById(R.id.editFileName);
    String fileName = fileInputField.getText().toString();

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open(fileName),
            StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        sb.append("\n").append(sc.next());
        

    }

    TextView displayAreaTextView = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
    displayAreaTextView.setText(sb.toString());
}

File outfile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "out.txt");
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(outfile);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(bw);


public void shift_lehmer3_mean(double[] a, int num_vals)
{
    int tracker = 0;
    double square=0;
    double cube=0;
    while (tracker > num_vals){
        square += Math.pow(a[tracker], 2);
        cube += Math.pow(a[tracker], 3);

    }
    double lehmer =(cube/square);
    int timer = 0;
    while (timer < 0)
    {
        double shiftValue = (a[timer]- lehmer);
        a[timer] = shiftValue;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the PrintWriter, therefore you could write the initialization of the writers into one statement.

```
File outfile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(null), "out.txt");
```

You can write into your file with `print`/`write`/`println()`/`printf()`/`format()`. As you want to use some formatting you should use `printf()`/`format()`. The formatting instruction `4s%n` shows the String value with at least 4 letter and then a linebreak.
The PrintWriter is usually used with try-with-resource, which will close the PrintWriter automatically within the implicite final block.

```
try(PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(outfile)))) {
    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        String value = sc.next();
        sb.append("\n").append(value);
        pw.printf("%4s%n", value);
    }
}
```

Comment: i did that and now the app won't open, do i have to add something to the strings xml file or not?

Comment: Did you debug the method `processPress`? Do you leave the while loop?

Comment: Could you say which change forces the app to keep close?

Comment: now it doesn't close but instead the code says it cannot resolve setText and sb, but again, do i need to change something in the strings xml or the activity_main xml or not?

Comment: I also left the while loop and android studio doesn't say theres anything to debug in processPress so, no I didnt debug

Comment: I don't think it depends on the Strings XML.

Comment: Remove `pw.printf("%4s%n", value);` from your code and check if the app works. If not restore `sb.append("\n").append(sc.next());`

Comment: still nothing. in addition, i'm getting messages saying the pw field is never used, the shift lehmer method is never used and the tracker, timer and num_vals variables are not updated in the loop. Now i don't even know if my code is even finding the new values with the lehmer mean

Comment: Please fix your code without my answer first. And afterwards add the file writing. Good luck.